# Wget Missing URL in cmd windows 8

Tags: windows, cmd, wget

Im using Wget 1.2 64bit for Windows 8. In CMD, I used this command to download files from facebook, but it gives error that

```
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
```

Command

```
wget  --header "origin: https://web.facebook.com" --header "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" --header "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8" --header "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Mobile Safari/537.36" --header "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "accept: */*" --header "referer: https://web.facebook.com/groups/Booooooks/files/" --header "authority: web.facebook.com" --header "cookie: sb=bKUwXJpWAe1SSNfwIDDsD8XN; datr=bKUwXEDW1b_pukzYrFFidfkz; c_user=100001863466617; xs=42^%^3AdXBOhMFarGS56g^%^3A2^%^3A1557410062^%^3A19008^%^3A5962; spin=r.1000696612_b.trunk_t.1557507467_s.1_v.2_; fr=0w2O4LxVaFNhqyrg3.AWUuDmmLnUnhm_CUzvBpimPX0No.BcMIBy.Zs.FzR.0.0.Bc1fRF.AWWEKwrf; wd=1360x657; presence=EDvF3EtimeF1557525751EuserFA21B01863466617A2EstateFDsb2F1557521405829EatF1557525746283Et3F_5bDiFA2user_3a1B00937247527A2ErF1EoF5EfF8C_5dEutc3F1557525409191G557525751464CEchFDp_5f1B01863466617F403CC; act=1557525832477^%^2F1270; x-src=^%^2Fgroups^%^2FBooooooks^%^2Ffiles^%^2F^%^7Cpagelet_bluebar; pnl_data2=eyJhIjoib25hZnRlcmxvYWQiLCJjIjoiL2dyb3Vwcy9wcm9maWxlLnBocDpmaWxlcyIsImIiOmZhbHNlLCJkIjoiL2dyb3Vwcy9Cb29vb29va3MvZmlsZXMvIiwiZSI6W119 --content-disposition -c -i list.txt
```

Comment: May be you shouldn't post all your cookies so publicly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at your command:

`wget  --header "origin: https://web.facebook.com" --header "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" --header "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8" --header "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Mobile Safari/537.36" --header "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "accept: */*" --header "referer: https://web.facebook.com/groups/Booooooks/files/" --header "authority: web.facebook.com" --header "cookie: sb=bKUwXJpWAe1SSNfwIDDsD8XN; datr=bKUwXEDW1b_pukzYrFFidfkz; c_user=100001863466617; xs=42^%^3AdXBOhMFarGS56g^%^3A2^%^3A1557410062^%^3A19008^%^3A5962; spin=r.1000696612_b.trunk_t.1557507467_s.1_v.2_; fr=0w2O4LxVaFNhqyrg3.AWUuDmmLnUnhm_CUzvBpimPX0No.BcMIBy.Zs.FzR.0.0.Bc1fRF.AWWEKwrf; wd=1360x657; presence=EDvF3EtimeF1557525751EuserFA21B01863466617A2EstateFDsb2F1557521405829EatF1557525746283Et3F_5bDiFA2user_3a1B00937247527A2ErF1EoF5EfF8C_5dEutc3F1557525409191G557525751464CEchFDp_5f1B01863466617F403CC; act=1557525832477^%^2F1270; x-src=^%^2Fgroups^%^2FBooooooks^%^2Ffiles^%^2F^%^7Cpagelet_bluebar; pnl_data2=eyJhIjoib25hZnRlcmxvYWQiLCJjIjoiL2dyb3Vwcy9wcm9maWxlLnBocDpmaWxlcyIsImIiOmZhbHNlLCJkIjoiL2dyb3Vwcy9Cb29vb29va3MvZmlsZXMvIiwiZSI6W119 --content-disposition -c -i list.txt`

... you'll see that the `--header "cookie: ...` option is missing its closing `"`.

That's why `--content-disposition -c -i list.txt` is interpreted as part of the `cookie` header.

Add the missing `"` after `...MvIiwiZSI6W119"`.